# orientation changed is not working

Tags: iphone, orientation, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

Thanks in advance

I want to detect when orientation changed in my device ...
for that I used this listener

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

and orientation changed method is

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(id)obj
{  
    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
        self.view=self.landscapeView;
        NSLog(@"landscapeView");

       //[self loadView1];
    }
    else 
    {
       self.view = self.portraitView;
       NSLog(@"portraitView");

       //[self loadView1];
    }    
}
```

and every time its went into that orientation which was on ViewDidLoad() methode ...

can any one help me..

Comment: -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  will call when device orientation change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this
[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
 if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) )
{
    //code here     
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your question was vert vague , This is a general explanation. You can override below mentioned methods to handle orientation changes

Over ride below mentioned methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   // return YES to supported orientation.
}

 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
/* Subclasses may override this method to perform additional actions immediately 
   prior to the rotation. For example, you might use this method to disable view 
   interactions, stop media playback, or temporarily turn off expensive drawing or live 
   updates. You might also use it to swap the current view for one that reflects the new
   interface orientation. When this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property 
   still contains the view’s original orientation. 
*/

}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    /*Subclasses may override this method to perform additional actions immediately after
      the rotation. For example, you might use this method to reenable view interactions, 
      start media playback again, or turn on expensive drawing or live updates. By the time 
      this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property is already set to the new 
      orientation.*/
}


- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    /*This method is called from within the animation block used to rotate the view. 
      You can override this method and use it to configure additional animations that should 
      occur during the view rotation. For example, you could use it to adjust the zoom level 
      of your content, change the scroller position, or modify other animatable properties
      of your view.*/
}
```

Don't check the device orientation in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear like this

```
    if( [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
OR if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
```

Because many times it will give un-expected results, like if the iPhone/iPad is placed on top of a table (I had experienced this...Very Nasty Issue).

This  [apple developer link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1) will give more info about handling orientations

Comment: Thanks, I am happy that my answer was useful for you.Please mark as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

change the following

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(id)obj
{  

  if( [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
  {
    self.view=self.landscapeView;
    NSLog(@"landscapeView");

    //[self loadView1];
  }
  else 
  {
    self.view = self.portraitView;
    NSLog(@"portraitView");

    //[self loadView1];
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` ?
it's the method in UIViewController that is already invoked...